# Is that possible to create a column inside other columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to create a column with python and pandas that aggregate two other columns
Like

Investiments (Columns
Jhon | Camile (2 different columns)

```py
test = {'Jhon':{'Investments':[100,200,300]},'Camile':{'Investments':[200.300,-150]}}

test2 = {'Investments':{'Jhon':[987,654,321], 'Camile':[654,321,159]}}
```

I tried to create a date frame from those two dictionaries, but, both failed to created the expected result on the DataFrame().
I guess this isn't possible, but, i just want to make sure.

The expected result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsoTx.png)

Comment: It is unclear from your question what you intended to achieve when combining the two dictionaries. I suggest providing a [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But do you mean a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)?

Comment: Sorry, let me try to make this more clear.
I want a columns of columns.

Comment: Please provide the expected dataframe

Comment: only 2 options are to use a multi-index or to create a column with some sort of list inside

Comment: Sorry guys, i created the question whiteout formatting, so, I edited,, and, I hope that  this editing made the question more clear, but, thanks for the attention.

Comment: Please don't provide code/data/error messages as images - post the text directly here on SO. Also, you should post your code to describe your approach and why it failed to achieve the desired output. The values in your example don't match those in the dictionaries, so it is unclear which value should end up in each column.

Comment: Mr. T, there is no "code/data/error messages as images", the only image i linked, was the expected result.
my examples do not match my expect result, because, the expected result, it is what i'm trying to achieve.
Those dictionaries was "tests".

Comment: Nobody knows what your expected output is with the current question. Please edit your question along the line 1) "These are the dictionaries dic1 and dic2 I wanted to combine." Done. 2) "df is the dataframe that I expected." Missing. 3) "My code XYZ did not generate a dataframe/the wrong dataframe/made my computer explode. How should I change my code?".  Missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
test3 = {('Investments','Jhon'):[987,654,321], ('Investments','Camile'):[654,321,159]}
pd.DataFrame(test3)
```

output

```
   Investments
   Jhon Camile
0   987 654
1   654 321
2   321 159
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, this isnexactily what o was searching for.